# Annotation (parameter) validation in Java?

Tags: java, validation, annotations

Is there any way to validate annotation validity in Java?

For example I may have an annotation

```
public @interface Foo {
   int number();
   String name();
}

public @interface Foos {
    Foo[] value();
    /* Foos() {
        for(int i=0; i<value().length; ++i) {
            if( i != value()[i].number() ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    } */
}
```

Can I constraint that `numbers` are starting from zero and go continuously?

(in example above I wrote this check in commented out annotation constructor)

**UPDATE**

Some samples of annotation usage:

```
// correctly annotated class
@Foos({@Foo(number=0, name="first"), @Foo(number=1,name="second")})
class MyCorrectAnnotatedClass {
}

// incorrectly annotated class 1
// number starts from 1 not form 0
@Foos({@Foo(number=1, name="first"), @Foo(number=2,name="second")})
class MyIncorrectAnnotatedClass1 {
}

// incorrectly annotated class 2
// number sequence has missed 1
@Foos({@Foo(number=0, name="first"), @Foo(number=2,name="second")})
class MyIncorrectAnnotatedClass2 {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to check all places where the annotation is used, so that each number is used exactly once starting from 0? That is not possible in a simple way.

If you really want to do this, you'd have to write code that scans all classes on the classpath, finds all classes that use the annotation, and then check the values of the annotations. (And if the annotation is used on methods or something else instead of classes, it's even more difficult).

You cannot add implementation code such as a constructor to an annotation. In that way, an annotation is similar to an interface.

Comment: Although I meant different thing you thought, but from your answer it is probably comes that the answer is "impossible". See my update please: I meant check annotation integrity in each single usage, not in all usages. Since annotations designed as independent entity, latter wish would be illegal.